Callback URL for SonarQube
My SonarQube version is 9.9.5. I'm trying to setup GitHub Authorization to allow users of my GitHub Organization to login to SonarQube. I tried to follow the documentation here but I'm unsure what is my callback URL. I've tried setting it the same as my Homepage URL / Server base URL but when I tried to login, I got redirected back to the login page with this link https://sonarqube.my.domain/sessions/new?return_to=%2Fcallback%3Ferror%3Dredirect_uri_mismatch%26error_description%3DThe%2Bredirect_uri%2BMUST%2Bmatch%2Bthe%2Bregistered%2Bcallback%2BURL%2Bfor%2Bthis%2Bapplication.%26error_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdocs.github.com%252Fapps%252Fmanaging-oauth-apps%252Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%252F%2523redirect-uri-mismatch%26state%3Dccgk5onvdgovo5nod56v5g7mu3
I tried to look for callback URL settings in the SonarQube settings page with no luck.
